# socketserver - allow_reuse_address to rebind existing port number not working without overriding class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple socket server using `socketserver` module, all seems to work just fine except just one small thing. I bind the server to some port and then set `server.allow_reuse_address = True` to reuse the same port without having to wait for the kernel to release the underlying port. However it does not work if modify the variable `server.allow_reuse_address = True` after creating the server instance, but if i create the custom class for the server and then override the variable in it, everything works.

Below is my code.

```
import socketserver
import sys

class MyTCPRequestehandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
        while self.data:
            print('Received {} from {}'.format(self.data.decode().strip(), self.client_address))
            self.request.send(self.data.upper())
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        server = socketserver.TCPServer(('', 12345), MyTCPRequestehandler)
        ip, port = server.server_address
        server.allow_reuse_address = True
        print(server.allow_reuse_address)
        print('Server listening on port {}'.format(port))
        # server.handle_request()
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```

I get this error if re-run the application, just after disconnecting

```
File "/Documents/PythonPrograms/network-modules/socketServer/simplesocketserver.py", line 16, in <module>
    server = socketserver.TCPServer(('', 12345), MyTCPRequestehandler)
  File "/spare/ssd/rbhanot/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/spare/ssd/rbhanot/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

However if i do something like below everything works.

```
class MyTcpServer(socketserver.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, address, request_handler_class):
        self.address = address
        self.request_handler_class = request_handler_class
        super().__init__(self.address, self.request_handler_class)
```

So what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected and documented behaviour. From https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/SocketServer.py:

> Class variables that may be overridden by derived classes or
>   instances:
>
> - timeout
> - address_family
> - socket_type
> - allow_reuse_address

And if we inspect the source code further, we can see the reason for this. The class init calls `server_bind()`, which is the function that checks the `allow_reuse_address` variable and does `setsockopt` accordingly if needed.

If you change it later, no further checks will be made after the instance initialisation, which means your change does not affect anything.

Comment: Thank you for this answer - I had the same issue and your explanation helped me reinterpret the docs: "This defaults to False, and can be set in subclasses to change the policy.". Specifically, it should be set in the _subclass_ as you describe, not an _instance_ of the subclass.